# Cannot find symbol in my return statement? Java

Tags: java

I've been trying to code this correctly for a good hour now and I can't figure out anything. This method calculates the cost of going to the movies with the number of adult tickets, student tickets, if it's a matinee, if it's on a weekday, and what movie they're going to see.

At first, I put in a return statement after each if statement and it said the method didn't have a return statement. Now, I put it near the end of the method and the variable *cost* isn't recognized, since *cost* is in the if statements.

Sorry about all the text. Here's the code.

```
public static int getCost (char movie, int month, int day, boolean isMatinee, int numberOfAdultTickets, int numberOfStudentTickets)
    {
        if (movie == 'C')
        {
            if (isWeekday(month, day))
            {
                if (isMatinee)
                {
                    int cost = (numberOfAdultTickets*8) + (numberOfStudentTickets*8);
                }
                else if (!isMatinee)
                {
                    int cost = (numberOfAdultTickets*10) + (numberOfStudentTickets*8);
                }
            }
            else if (!isWeekday(month, day))
            {
                if (isMatinee)
                {
                    int cost = (numberOfAdultTickets*11) + (numberOfStudentTickets*11);
                }
                if (!isMatinee)
                {
                    int cost = (numberOfAdultTickets*13) + (numberOfStudentTickets*11);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (movie == 'G')
        {
            if (isWeekday(month, day))
            {
                if (isMatinee)
                {
                    int cost = (numberOfAdultTickets*6) + (numberOfStudentTickets*6);
                }
                else if (!isMatinee)
                {
                    int cost = (numberOfAdultTickets*8) + (numberOfStudentTickets*6);
                }
            }
            else if (!isWeekday(month, day))
            {
                if (isMatinee)
                {
                    int cost = (numberOfAdultTickets*9) + (numberOfStudentTickets*9);
                }
                else if (!isMatinee)
                {
                    int cost = (numberOfAdultTickets*11) + (numberOfStudentTickets*9);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (movie == 'P')
        {
            if (isWeekday(month, day))
            {
                if (isMatinee)
                {
                    int cost = (numberOfAdultTickets*6) + (numberOfStudentTickets*6);
                }
                else if (!isMatinee)
                {
                    int cost = (numberOfAdultTickets*8) + (numberOfStudentTickets*6);
                }
            }
            else if (!isWeekday(month, day))
            {
                if (isMatinee)
                {
                    int cost = (numberOfAdultTickets*9) + (numberOfStudentTickets*9);
                }
                else if (!isMatinee)
                {
                    int cost = (numberOfAdultTickets*11) + (numberOfStudentTickets*9);
                }
            }
        }
        return cost;
    }
```

Comment: Where is `cost` declared? Look into variable scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the cost veriable in the method scope, out side the if statements, like

```
int cost = 0;
if (movie == 'C')
    {
        if (isWeekday(month, day))
        {
            if (isMatinee)
            {
                cost = (numberOfAdultTickets*8) + (numberOfStudentTickets*8);
            }
            else if (!isMatinee)
            {
                cost = (numberOfAdultTickets*10) + (numberOfStudentTickets*8);
            }
        }
    } else if... //rest of your code.

    return cost;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solves your problem :

```
public static int getCost (char movie, int month, int day, boolean isMatinee, int numberOfAdultTickets, int numberOfStudentTickets)
{
 int cost = 0
//there will be the rest of code you already have
}
```

However the biggest problem is that if-else craziness :). Look to how to use classes.